# Match expression on Int is not exhaustive

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

I've started learning Scala.

I was surprised that next code compiles:

```scala
object Hello extends App {
  def isOne(num: Int) = num match {
    case 1 => "hello"
  }
}
```

You can't do something similar in Rust for example.

Why Scala compiler does not force me to provide default value for `case` ?

I'd say that it is a little bit unsafe.

Is there any scala linter or something else? Maybe some flags?

Comment: It does ... With appropriate options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [Scala 2.13.4](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.4) there were improvement to exhaustivity checking of unsealed types such as `Int` so try with compiler flag

```
-Xlint:strict-unsealed-patmat
```

for example

```
scala -Xlint:strict-unsealed-patmat -Xfatal-warnings
Welcome to Scala 2.13.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_275).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def isOne(num: Int) = num match {
     |     case 1 => "hello"
     |   }
                             ^
       warning: match may not be exhaustive.
       It would fail on the following input: (x: Int forSome x not in 1)
error: No warnings can be incurred under -Werror.
```

In general though, according to [Pattern Matching Expressions](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-expressions)

> If the selector of a pattern match is an instance of a **sealed** class,
> the compilation of pattern matching can emit warnings which diagnose
> that a given set of patterns is not exhaustive, i.e. that there is a
> possibility of a MatchError being raised at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can deal with it a bit on structural matching, by setting
"-Xfatal-warnings" option in scalac settings, this will lift this and other warnings to errors.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? So other persons who will face same issue will get solution